# How to make java mail to interpret more than 1 space in mail?

Tags: java, html, email, jakarta-mail

I want to do some type of mail designing by entering spaces so that all data shown in it is shown like if it was an HTML table, so it would show like an HTML table although without borders, but java mail seems to ignore when there are several spaces together and reduces them all to just one. I've tried to write an space in HTML code and I've also tested with entering \t so it would make a similar function, but it doesn't help.

I wouldn't like to do this in HTML code as email servers use to give problems when receiving this type of code, I'd better do it on plain text.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the `MediaType` you are passing in mail `Message`?

Comment: What mail client do you use?

Comment: *"I've tried to write an space in HTML code and I've also tested with entering \t so it would make a similar function, but it doesn't help."*  HTML is mark-up, not code.  But besides that, unless the section is marked something like `pre` or `code` then multiple spaces will typically be compacted, and tabs will look like a single space.  So that leads me to..  Can you produce the right effect in plain HTML?  If not, it is not going to work in an HTML formatted email.  Get it working in HTML (viewed in a browser) and it should work in an email.

Comment: Also, if you want to create something _like_ an HTML table without borders, why not create an _actual_ HTML table, and set it not to have borders?

Comment: At first I wasn't declaring any media type, so I guess it was using its default one, I've changed it to utf-8 but it keeps the same, I'll be testing some more just in case, mail client can be anyone, that's the reason it's being done by entering spaces.

Comment: I'm not into creating it as HTML table as email servers use to give problems when reading Html code, at least the ones I've seen.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to create an e-mail message consisting of plain-text content, and you want the text to be column-aligned, essentially forming a plain-text table.  Set the message's content type to text/plain.  An easy way to do this is with any of the [`setText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods.

Comment: Hi, I've checked that interpretation of spaces depends on email server, as, for example in gmail spaces do display while not in hotmail, taking into consideration that my application might send an email to any existing email direction I guess this cannot be helped, so I'll just stick with just one space although it looks less appealing.